# What is good way to pick good matches in Android OpenCV 2.4.4

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing a program to recognize banknotes. Below is my function to find matches. I have 5 images from phone memory and one image taken via camera. This code is being executed in for loop to find images with the most amount of matches. What is good way to get good matches from variable matches?

```
object_desc = new Mat();
scene_desc = new Mat();

object_keys = new MatOfKeyPoint();
scene_keys = new MatOfKeyPoint();

matches = new MatOfDMatch();
good_matches = new MatOfDMatch();

Utils.bitmapToMat(image, object); 
surf = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
surf.detect(object, object_keys);
surf.detect(mRgba, scene_keys);

surfEX = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.FREAK);
surfEX.compute(object, object_keys, object_desc);
surfEX.compute(mRgba, scene_keys, scene_desc);
dm = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

dm.match(object_desc, scene_desc, matches);
```

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865225/opencl-android-image-recognizing You can look at some example of picking good matches

Comment: need help. any findings?